# How to update one column of table with 8 million rows of data in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with about 20 columns. It currently holds 8 million rows of data.
I need to update one `NULL` column for all 8 million rows, it is a `GUID` column and a `FK` for another table column.

Currently, I am running simple update query in a loop. But it is taking way too long.

```
DO $$
BEGIN
   FOR counter IN 1..1000 LOOP

        UPDATE "Shops"
         SET "Country" = '410006e1-ca4e-4502-a9ec-e54d922d2c00'
         FROM (SELECT "Id"
                  FROM "Shops"
                   WHERE "Country" IS NULL LIMIT 1000) 
         AS "part"
         WHERE "Shops"."Id" = "part"."Id";

         COMMIT;
      RAISE NOTICE 'Counter: %', counter;

   END LOOP;
END; $$
```

Comment: Is GUID a fixed value?

Comment: @kometen yes it is

Comment: Why don't you directly update the table without loop?

Comment: @Popeye if i write just update, it worked for 6 hours yesterday, then i cancelled it. this way i see if it is working or not.

Comment: Updating 8 million rows shouldn't take 6 hours. Most probably your UPDATE was waiting for a lock due to other concurrent modifications. Doing that in batches won't make those locks go away and is typically slower than one large transaction

Comment: Completely unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Comment: How slow is it?  Do an `explain (analyze, buffers)` on your query to see why it is so slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating 8 million rows should not take 6 hours.  But it can take a long time.  It is often faster to just repopulate the table:

```
create table temp_shops as
    select . . . ,
           '410006e1-ca4e-4502-a9ec-e54d922d2c00' as country,
            . . . 
    from shops
    where country is null;
```

Once you have tested this to be sure it does what you want, you can truncate the table and insert the values:

```
truncate table shops;  -- be careful.  This empties the table but you have a copy!

insert into shops ( . . . )
    select *
    from temp_shops;
```